# Spring controller not created

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

There is a small Struts application and I am trying to enable Spring-mvc on it. It's already using Spring to handle the DB transactions. I have two questions:

- Component scan will not pick up my controllers if I try to add a new base package.
- If I place my controllers in an existing base package, I can see them created in Spring application context. But then the request mapping still does not work.

Here are my relevant code snippets:

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.site</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is springDispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycom.eps.test, com.mycom.epsadmin"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionHandler" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error"/>
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException">jdbcerror</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here's part of ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycom.eps, com.mycom.tiff" />  
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

I've got two Controllers:

```
package com.mycom.eps.test;
// import statements
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws EpsException {
        Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        return new ModelAndView("/details", modelMap);
    }
}
```

Another controller:

```
//This is a new package I am trying to create
package com.mycom.epsadmin.controller;
// import statements
@Controller
public class PackageController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/sendPackage", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView sendPackage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws EpsException {
        Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        return new ModelAndView("/details", modelMap);
    }
}
```

My first question is, why is the com.mycom.epsadmin.controller.PackageController never created in web application context (I inspected the spring log and couldn't find it)?

While trying to figure out about my first question, I created another controller com.mycom.eps.test.TestController (hence the name of the controller). While this one does get created in the Web application context, the request is never intercepted (404 error).
Here's how I am trying to call it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.site",
    cache: false
});
```

When I try to go to the page through browser http://http://localhost:8080/mycom/test.site, I am getting 404 error as well.

Sorry for the lengthy post! But can someone kindly point me in the right direction? Thanks a bunch!

**UPDATE:**

Just found out that the test controller is actually picking up the request (really sorry about that)! So my second question is moot.

Comment: you may want try changing url from test.site to test in your ajax

Comment: I tried that. But it did not work either. In web.xml, it does set up the url pattern as follows: <url-pattern>*.site</url-pattern>

Answer (score 1):

Try after adding `com.mycom.epsadmin` in the ApplicationContext

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycom.epsadmin, com.mycom.eps, com.mycom.tiff" />
```

Comment: I have tried that too. I still can't find the PackageController instance created in the web application context, and also am getting the 404.